# jquery post Showing loading message till success

Tags: php, jquery

I have following script which fetch data from server based on form parameters.

```
 jQuery('#request_search').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); 


        var s_date=jQuery('#actualfrom').val();
        var e_date=jQuery('#actualto').val();
        var type=jQuery("#type").val();
        var loc=jQuery("#loc").val();



 jQuery.post("scripts/get_gamma_activity_type.php", {"loc":loc,"start_date":s_date, "end_date":e_date, "type":type},  function(data) { 

 jQuery('#report').html(data);});


         });



});
```

This part is working and some times, based on search criteria , it takes a couple of seconds to get results. in the mean time I would like to show some GIF saying data loading. I have the GIF ready. How to implement it in the above script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this.

```
jQuery('#request_search').submit(function(e){

       $("#report").html("<div><img src='loading.gif' alt='Loading.. \n Please wait' title='Loading.. \n Please wait'` /></div>");
     e.preventDefault(); 


        var s_date=jQuery('#actualfrom').val();
        var e_date=jQuery('#actualto').val();
        var type=jQuery("#type").val();
        var loc=jQuery("#loc").val();



 jQuery.post("scripts/get_gamma_activity_type.php", {"loc":loc,"start_date":s_date, "end_date":e_date, "type":type},  function(data) { 

 jQuery('#report').html(data);});
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add **Image with path** in your **html** file with **id** attribute and then show/hide div
>   based on request and success.

Try below code:

Add html div in your **html** file :

```
  <div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
  <img src='loadinggraphic.gif'/>
  </div>
```

Try below code of **jQuery**:

```
jQuery('#request_search').submit(function(e){


$('#loadingmessage').show();  // show the loading message.
     e.preventDefault(); 


        var s_date=jQuery('#actualfrom').val();
        var e_date=jQuery('#actualto').val();
        var type=jQuery("#type").val();
        var loc=jQuery("#loc").val();



 jQuery.post("scripts/get_gamma_activity_type.php", {"loc":loc,"start_date":s_date, "end_date":e_date, "type":type},  function(data) { 

 jQuery('#report').html(data);});
   $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message
         });
});
```

Comment: Should you delete the #loading img in the success function?

Comment: @mansoondreamz its standard way to do ajax image loading becuase using .html method you need to put whole html code in js file so
anyways thanks